# presenting resources in API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-grape, presenter

im preparing Rails 5 API and i have some GET endpoints which do nothing but presenting resources to enduser.

how can i limit what the user can see. Lets say i have a table `Books`, with `title` and `author` columns, i want the enduser to get his `book` with a `title` and an `author` but i dont want to give him stuff like :id or timestamps. is there an existing solution similar to what grape has to offer with `present()` and `Grape::Entity` classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way to do this would be with a serializer.

```
# app/serializers/book_serializer.rb
class BookSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :title, :author
end
```

Then in the controller:

```
def show
  book = Book.find(params[:id])
  render json: book, serializer: BookSerializer
end
```